# Registros duplicados con INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, select, inner

Estoy validando los registros posterior a la rotación de una particion.

Al ejecutar el SELECT COUNT para cada tabla obtengo 114817959 registros.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerf]  WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE DateEntered >='2021-09-01 00:00:00.000'
AND DateEntered<'2021-10-01 00:00:00.000'


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerfHistory]  WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE DateEntered >='2021-09-01 00:00:00.000'
AND DateEntered<'2021-10-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Sin embargo, cuando realizó el INNER JOIN los registros duplicados no me permiten visualizar la información correctamente ya que obtengo 130962977 registros

```
SELEC COUNT(*)
  FROM [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerf] MP WITH (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerfHistory] MH WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON MP.RowId=MH.RowId
  AND MP.[DateEntered]=MH.[DateEntered] 
  WHERE MP.DateEntered >='2021-09-01 00:00:00.000'
  and MP.DateEntered<'2021-10-01 00:00:00.000'
```

En esta ocasión solo es validación la que necesito realizar mediante el SELECT, al ser una tabla histórica no pretendo borrar los duplicados .

Me pueden asesorar sobre la manera en la que podría ejecutar el inner  para que los registros duplicados no alteren el resultado final,por favor

Comment: Seguramente en  `MessagesPerfHistory` tiene algún `RowId` repetido, de ahi que te aparezcan filas "duplicadas". ¿Qué hay que hacer en estos casos? ¿con cual de lo registros "duplicados" de `MessagesPerfHistory` nos tenemos que quedar?

Comment: Si obtienes los registros correctos con una tabla ¿Por qué necesitas usar ambas? Tu llave está incompleta y el conjunto de RowId y DateEntered no forman valores únicos. Necesitas redefinir la llave para unir las tablas.

Comment: Cuidado con `WITH (NOLOCK)`. Con `NOLOCK` volontariamente acceptas resultados incorrectes. Es una function profesional para situaciònes muy especiales y raras, y sea mejor que nunco lo uses.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que yo haria vendria siendo una subconsulta y aplicar groupBy algo asi.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalRegistros
FROM (
 SELECT MP.RowId, COUNT(*) as     Numeroregistros
FROM [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerf] MP WITH         (NOLOCK)
 INNER JOIN [SMS].[dbo].    [MessagesPerfHistory] MH WITH (NOLOCK)
ON MP.RowId = MH.RowId
 AND MP.[DateEntered] = MH.[DateEntered] 
WHERE MP.DateEntered >= '2021-09-01     00:00:00.000'
 AND MP.DateEntered < '2021-10-01          00:00:00.000'
 GROUP BY MP.RowId
 ) AS ResultadoRegistro;
```

Algo asi entiendo yo, no tengo conocimiento bien sobre tu bd enrealidad

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas hacer es validar que todos los registros de "MessagesPerf" existan en el histórico, podrías hacer algo así en vez de un JOIN:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerf] MP  WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE MP.DateEntered >= '2021-09-01 00:00:00.000'
        AND MP.DateEntered < '2021-10-01 00:00:00.000'
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerfHistory] WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE RowId = MP.RowId
                AND DateEntered = MP.DateEntered
        ) --Sólo trae los que existan en la tabla histórica
```

Sino con el mismo JOIN escrito en la pregunta, si sólo quieres obtener la cantidad de RowId distintos que existen puedes utilizar COUNT(DISTINCT RowID):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MP.RowId)
  FROM [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerf] MP WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerfHistory] MH WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON MP.RowId=MH.RowId
        AND MP.[DateEntered]=MH.[DateEntered] 
  WHERE MP.DateEntered >='2021-09-01 00:00:00.000'
    and MP.DateEntered<'2021-10-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu consulta asumes que solo hay un registro por RowId y DateEntered. Pero esto no es así, y por eso hay duplicados en tus tablas.

Por ejemplo si hay dos registros con RowId = 1 y DateEntered = 2021-09-05 en cada tabla, entonces recibes cuatro registros, porque cada de los dos registros de una table tiene dos coincidencias en la otra table. Asi se producen duplicadas de las duplicadas.

Asi puedes encontrar las duplicadas en una tabla:

```
SELECT RowId, [DateEntered]
FROM [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerf]
GROUP BY RowId, [DateEntered]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I puedes usar el resultado para ver los registros para decidir que hacer. Puede que queras borrar los duplicados. O puede que identifiques otro columna que nececitas añadir al las condiciónes del join.

```
WITH
  duplicados AS
  (
    SELECT RowId, [DateEntered]
    FROM [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerf]
    GROUP BY RowId, [DateEntered]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
SELECT *
FROM [SMS].[dbo].[MessagesPerf] mp
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM duplicados d
  WHERE d.RowId = mp.RowId
  AND d.[DateEntered] = mp.[DateEntered]
)
ORDER BY RowId, [DateEntered];
```